# navbar menu slide down slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have implemented a `tree-view` navbar. Now I am trying to do when clicking the menu list slides down slowly. But my tried code is not working. How can I do this?

I have mentioned my tried code below -->

```
<ul>
  <div class="cls2">
    <li>
      <ul class="nested nav nav-pills flex-column tog">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a>lable</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use `next()` to grab the correct body element. Then `slideToggle()` like this:

```
$(".treeparent").click(function () {
  $(this).next('.tog').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding transition to the element your sliding with css

```
transition: all 0.3s; // example
```

Comment: I added this `.tog{ transition: all 0.3s; }` but not works as expected.

Comment: try changing the height instead of sliding the elements

Comment: I did not get what you said above `try changing the height instead of sliding the elements`

Comment: In my project i set the `li` element to `max-height: 0;` and then changing the the `li` i clicked with `max-height: 1000px;` with the transition i was saying, sorry for the explanation. (for `li` i mean the content)

Comment: another tip i can give you is to check if the js script really get the element you want to change (maybe try to change the text or the color just to be sure it get the element)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav-item').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
  $(this).find('.tog').first().stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
});

$('.nav-item').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
  $(this).find('.tog').first().stop(true, true).slideUp('fast');
});
```

Slide up Down Fast is parameter or you can use Slow